# Disposable Cellphone SIM Card for Germany

Tags: germany, cellphones, internet, communication

I am coming to Germany for holidays, and I would life to use my cell phone, however I guess a German provider may be able to offer a much better service of Internet connections. But since this is temporary trip, I don't wanna buy a full plan.

Are there SIM Cards for me to buy in Frankfurt Airport or Frankfurt area?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to deal with this question. Greg is correct, that this is a duplicate of the question he is referring to. The almost 3 years old answer is however severely outdated.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Post a new answer. That's why we leave questions open, even after they've been answered.